# Compare a table to itself

Tags: sql

I am trying to compare the same table to itself to compare One employees Locations to another.  I want to be able to select if One employee is only at a certain location from another employee.

The Table looks like this

```
StaffNo  LocoNo
1          1
1          2
1          3
3          2
3          3
3          4
4          1
4          2
5          2
5          3
6          1
6          2
```

Say Compare Staff 1 and 4

Results would be

```
StaffNo  LocoNo
1          3
```

I have tried an inner join and an EXCEPT but it seems like it does not work.

Comment: Do you want "Locations where the first StaffNo is present, but the second isn't" or "Locations where only one of the following two staff are present"? I.e. is the search meant to be indifferent to the order you've given the two staff numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT StaffNo
     , LocoNo
  FROM Tbl A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM Tbl B
        WHERE A.StaffNo <> B.StaffNo
          AND A.LocoNo = B.LocoNo)
```

Comment: I used your example and played with it a little to get it to work. Here is what I finally got to do the job from your example.                                                      SELECT StaffNo, LocoNo
  FROM Tbl A
 WHERE A.StaffNo = 1
AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM Tbl B
        WHERE B.StaffNo = 4
          AND A.LocoNo = B.LocoNo)

Answer (score 1):

An inner join only returns results when both sides of the join match. As you're looking for differences, you want an outer join. Like this.

```
select 
    COALESCE(t1.staffid, t2.staffid) as staff,
    COALESCE(t1.locationid, t2.locationid) as location 
from
    (select * from table where staffid=1) t1
        full outer join
    (select * from table where staffid=4) t2    
        on t1.locationid = t2.locationid
where t1.locationid is null 
or t2.locationid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using MINUS / UNION ALL:

```
with 
  v_1 as (select locono from from table where staffid=1),
  v_2 as (select locono from from table where staffid=2)
select * from (
(select 1 staffid, locono from v_1
 minus
 select 1 staffid, locono from v_2
)
union all
(
select 2 staffid, locono from v_2
 minus
 select 2 staffid, locono from v_1
)) order by staffid, locono
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select staffno,locono from tbl where staffno in (1,4) and locono in
((select locono from tbl where staffno = 1
except
select locono from tbl where staffno = 4)
union 
(select locono from tbl where staffno = 4
except
select locono from tbl where staffno = 1))
```